# Unable to push string into array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, ejs

I am trying to learn EJS and make a blog but I cant seem to understand this error

What I am trying to do is try to write some db response as an Object to an array then push it to the file.
I am using replit DB

```js
const fs = require("fs")
const Database = require("@replit/database")
const db = new Database()

exports.load = async function(){
  db.set("hello", {
    "author": "Some author 1",
    "title": "Blog Post 1",
    "content": "First post content",
    "date_posted": "Dec 17, 2021"
  })

  var posts = new Array()

  db.list().then(keys => {
    keys.forEach(key => {
      posts.push(`      <article class="media content-section">
        <div class="media-body">
          <div class="article-metadata">
            <a class="mr-2" href="/p">Anonymous</a>
            <small class="text-muted">${db.get(key).date_posted}</small>
          </div>
          <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">${ db.get(key).title }</a></h2>
          <p class="article-content">${ db.get(key).content }</p>
        </div>
      </article`
      )
    })
  });

  posts = posts.join()

  fs.writeFileSync("public/posts.ejs", posts)
}
```

Error that I am getting when I run the code:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: posts.push is not a function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you declare `var posts = new Array()`. So `posts` is an array. Next line (in execution order) : `posts = posts.join()`. So now `posts` is an empty string. You are changing the type of the variable, which is a bad practice (Typescript wouldn't let you do that). Now next line in execution order : `.then(keys =>`. You start pushing stuff into `posts`, but `posts` is now a string, remember? Not an array anymore.

You use the `async` keyword for no reason, since there is no `await` in it. You might as well leverage it :

```
exports.load = async function(){
  db.set("hello", {
    "author": "Some author 1",
    "title": "Blog Post 1",
    "content": "First post content",
    "date_posted": "Dec 17, 2021"
  })

  let postsArray = new Array();

  const keys = await db.list();

  keys.forEach(key => {
    postsArray.push(`<article class="media content-section">
      <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
          <a class="mr-2" href="/p">Anonymous</a>
          <small class="text-muted">${db.get(key).date_posted}</small>
        </div>
        <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">${ db.get(key).title }</a></h2>
        <p class="article-content">${ db.get(key).content }</p>
      </div>
    </article`
    )
  })
  
  const posts = postsArray.join()

  fs.writeFileSync("public/posts.ejs", posts)
}
```

OR with .map() in one line :

```
exports.load = async function(){
  db.set("hello", {
    "author": "Some author 1",
    "title": "Blog Post 1",
    "content": "First post content",
    "date_posted": "Dec 17, 2021"
  })

  const keys = await db.list();

  const posts = keys.map( key => `<article class="media content-section">....</article`).join();

  fs.writeFileSync("public/posts.ejs", posts)
}
```